# Is it possible to remove parts or sections of the documents in the corpus of the R tm package?

Tags: r, tm, corpus

I have built a corpus with the R tm package consisting of several papers and I would like to remove the Reference section of all al them. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean a section within the documents? Yes:

```
library(tm)
txt <- c("Reference Section 1: Foo", "Reference Section 2: Bar")
corp <- Corpus(VectorSource(txt))
removeRefSec <- content_transformer(function(x) sub("^Reference Section \\d+: ", "", x))

corp[[1]]
# <<PlainTextDocument>>
# Metadata:  7
# Content:  chars: 24

removeRefSec(corp[[1]])
# <<PlainTextDocument>>
# Metadata:  7
# Content:  chars: 3

corp <- tm_map(corp, removeRefSec)
corp[[2]]
# <<PlainTextDocument>>
# Metadata:  7
# Content:  chars: 3
```